# How to keep last login shell as current shell in next login?

Tags: command-line

As title, How to keep last login shell as current shell in next login? for example my default shell is 'bash' and I switched to 'zsh', how can I have 'zsh' shell as my current shell in next login or open terminal?

Comment: How exactly would you switch to `zsh` in your current session? Simply type `zsh` to run an interactive Z-shell inside your Bash shell?

Comment: yes, and I don't want to change default to zsh, if next time I open terminal I should be in zsh shell, and same if I type bash and login in next time it should be in bash shell

Comment: So you want to keep the Bash default shell, but load your last manually called shell as subshell inside it automatically?

Comment: yes, correct. is it possible? also please consider if I didn't call another subshell, it should not create new 'bash' shell session under default bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a command in your `.bash_logout` and `.zlogout` files to change the current login shell to the one you're using.

The command could be

```
chsh -s "$(which "$(ps -p $$ -ocomm=)")" $USER
```

Since, `.bash_logout` and `.zlogout` is supposed to be sourced before exiting shell, this should change the login shell to the currently running shell. However, you'll need to give password to change the shell before exiting.

I used the information from [this question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on) and tested with `zsh` and `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for password to log out is silly. I wrote some code ages ago that would check the system for the most suitable shell. It will serve here.

1) Shell must be set to /bin/sh

2) .profile contains the following

```
. $HOME/.shell
if which $SHELL >/dev/null
then :
else SHELL=/bin/sh
     PROFILE=$HOME/.sh_profile
fi
export SHELL
BASHRC=$HOME/.bashrc
ZSHRC=$HOME/.zshrc
KSHRC=$HOME/.kshrc

# Don't do this dumb thing on X login
# The redirects on tty are for portability
if tty -s 1<&0 2<&0
then
    exec $SHELL -sc
fi
```

2) .sh_profile can be blank but this is better:

```
cd() { command cd $1 && PS1="`pwd`"\$\ }
PS1="`pwd`"\$\
```

3) .bashrc contains the following:

```
[ -f $HOME/.bash_shell ] && rm $HOME/.shell && ln $HOME/.bash_shell $HOME/.shell
```

4) .bash_shell contains the following

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PROFILE=$HOME/.bash_profile
```

same for other shells